# C# DateTime to W3CDTF

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I can't seem to find anything on the nets on how to do this, but does anyone know how to format a C# DateTime in the W3CDTF format?

specifically, something like this: `1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00` with the timezone offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, .NET does not contain a standard format for the W3C-compliant DateTime (see the specification on http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).
W3C-compliant string containing date and time are very useful since this is the standard format for many technologies such as Sitemaps, PingBack, RSS and so on.

[From Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#2)

What they recommend is `AnyValidDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u").Replace(" ", "T");`

Answer (score 9):

Use a [custom date and time format string](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx&ei=t7jLTcTmMoKzhAemyuGoAg&usg=AFQjCNELw0kR49xnfWouRbsZ4xyGSUcSKQ).

```
var formatted = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");
```